# Is it possible to dynamically change MS - SimpleMembership database connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, multi-tenant, simplemembership

I'm having the following scenario: I'm working on a multi-tenant application that requires to redirect Database operations to each client DB. So when a user connects to the application, the system uses that client DB to process his actions and operations.

I decided to use the default MVC 4 - SimpleMemberShip provider to handle Membership operations, however, I'm facing the problem that **"WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection method can be called only once".**

Thus, **I'm trap on using one single DB for all users of the system**, even if they have their own Database  with SimpleMemberShip tables created on them.

So I'm wondering, Is there a way to either reconnect WebSecutiry.Login each time for SimpleMemberShip, or to dynamically change the DB connection so it goes to the proper client DB to validate user credentials?

Something like:

```
 WebSecurity. <ChangeConnection> or <ReinitConnection>
 bool result = WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)
```

Comment: If you're building a multi-tenant solution, shouldn't each tenant be completely partitioned off from each other and thus have their own app instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible with [WebSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) class.As the error said you can't call `InitializeDatabaseConnection` method twice. But if you want to use `SimpleMembersip Provider` you can write your own [Custom Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) System and then you can add methods like `InitializeDatabase` and `ReInitializeDatabase` or `ChangeDatabase` etc., however you like.But as i said unfortunately it's not possible with `WebSecurity` class.